# Continuous wavelet transform of a periodic function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, signal-analysis, wavelets

I have a question regarding the Continuous Wavelet Transform (CWT) of non finite energy functions, such as $g(t) = a\exp(i\omega_0t)$. We know that the CWT is defined for functions in the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, but I've found in Chapter 4 of "A Wavelet Tour of Signal Processing" that the CWT of $g(t)$ is $(W_\psi g)(u,s) = a\sqrt{s}\hat{\psi^*}(s\omega_0)\exp(i\omega_0u)$, where $\psi$ is a wavelet. How is this possible ? (since $g \not\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$)

Comment: @username $f$ is a function in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, $s$ and $u$ are the scale and time localization parameters of the CWT. $W_\psi f$ is the CWT operator applied on $f$.

Comment: @username I'm sorry, it is the CWT of $g$.

Comment: @username You are right, the correct expression is  $(W_\psi g)(u,s) = a\sqrt{s}\hat{\psi^*}(s\omega_0)\exp(i\omega_0u)$.

Comment: If $\psi$ is well behaved, that is, $\psi$ is compactly supported, or exponentially decreasing at infinity, then the transform is well defined as well, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

For a Gabor wavelet, I guess that, up to  a different normalization, you have
\begin{align}
&(W_\psi g)(y,\eta)=\langle g(x),e^{-π(x-y)^2} e^{2iπ (x-y/2)\eta}\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb R)}
=\int g(x)e^{-π(x-y)^2} e^{-2iπ (x-y/2)\eta} dx
\\&=\int g(x+y)e^{-πx^2} e^{-2iπ (x+y/2)\eta} dx
=a\int e^{2iπ\omega_0(x+y)}e^{-πx^2} e^{-2iπ (x+y/2)\eta} dx
\\&=ae^{2iπ\omega_0 y-iπ y\eta}
\int e^{-πx^2}e^{-2iπ x(\eta-\omega_0)} dx=
ae^{iπy(2\omega_0 -\eta)}e^{-π(\eta-\omega_0)^2},
\end{align}
a formula rather similar to yours.